# conditioning problem

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with $P(X=1)=P(X=2)= \frac{1}{2}$, and let the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ be an exponential with rate $X$. Find $E[Y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Y]$.

What I could think of is to use the fact that $E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]$. So I got
$$
E[Y]=E[Y|X=1]P(X=1)+E[Y|X=2]P(X=2).
$$
Am I going to the right direction?

Comment: Yes, now just sort out the pdf of $Y$ given $X$ and use the conditional mean definition:$\mathbf{E}[Y|X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}y f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track!

For a fixed number $x$, an exponential variable with rate $x$ has mean $\frac{1}{x}$; so, $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=\frac{1}{X}$.

To see this more formally: an exponential variable with rate $x$ has density $p(t)=xe^{-xt}$. So, conditioned on $X=1$, $Y$ is exponential distributed with rate $1$ and therefore has density $p(t)=e^{-t}$, and we get
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=1]=\int_{0}^{\infty}t\,p(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\infty}te^{-t}\,dt=1=\frac{1}{1}.
$$
Similarly, conditioned on $X=2$, $Y$ is exponentially distributed with rate $2$ and therefore has density $p(t)=2e^{-2t}$, and so
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=2]=\int_0^{\infty}t\,p(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\infty}2te^{-2t}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
So, notice: in each case, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=\frac{1}{X}$!
Thus, as you point out,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]=\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}.
$$
Now, you need to compute the variance.  But remember, we can write variance as an expectation:
$$
\text{Var}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^2]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-\mathbb{E}[Y]^2.
$$
So, you are left to do the same thing here as you did before, but now for $Y^2$ instead of $Y$.  So, you need to try to get a handle on $\mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X]$.

Comment: I understand most of your reasoning but I am stuck at one point, how could you get E[Y∣X]=1/X?

Comment: @user113368 I expanded on it a bit more. Take a look!

Comment: This is really helpful! I totally understand now

Comment: @user113368 I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Another way (slower):
$$
\mathbf{E}Y= \mathbf{E}[Y|X=1]P(X=1)+\mathbf{E}[Y|X=2]P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}dy + 1 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-2y}dy\\
=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 +1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}\\
\mathbf{Var}Y=\mathbf{E}Y^2-(\mathbf{E}Y)^2 = \mathbf{E}[Y^2|X=1]P(X=1)+\mathbf{E}[Y^2|X=2]P(X=2)-(\mathbf{E}Y)^2\\
\mathbf{E}[Y^2|X=1]=\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-y}dy\\
\mathbf{E}[Y^2|X=2]=2 \int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-2y}dy
$$

Comment: is this missing the -E[Y]^2 term? since Var[Y]= E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2 which would be 5/4-(3/4)^2=11/16

Comment: yes, I corrected it

Comment: however I calulated with the normal expectation formula, I didnt get 5/8 but 11/16  because it becomes 1+1/4-9/16 trying to find out what went wrong...

Comment: You're right, see the edit.